# How to add specific label to ConfigMap using Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I am searching for a way to add a specific label to ConfigMap using Kustomize. Using `commonLabels` is not an option because it adds a label to every resource. For config map generation, I am using the following:

```
configMapGenerator:
- name: ${REPOSITORY_NAME}-env
  envs:
  - .env
```

And I would like to achieve something like this:

```
configMapGenerator:
- name: ${REPOSITORY_NAME}-env
  labels:
    key: value
  envs:
  - .env
```

Comment: You could move the configmapGenerator to its own directory with only this file and be able to use commonLabels in this directory. Then use the directory as a base in orher directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [git link](https://github.com/keleustes/kustomize/tree/allinone/examples/issues/issue_1501) you can add specific labels by using patch files in kustomize.

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> data:
>   a: "0"
> kind: ConfigMap
> metadata:
>   labels:
>     apps: a
>   name: a-config-map-26kgmbk2md
> ```
>
> Then add these in the configMapGenerator
>
> ```
> configMapGenerator:
>   - name: a-config-map
>     envs:
>       - a.properties
> patchesStrategicMerge:
>   - patch-a.yaml
> ```

This will add the specific label to individual configMaps to the configmap generator.

Additionally you can also refer to this [git issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/3108#issuecomment-710344736) for additional information.

Comment: thanks, I haven't thought that this could be achieved this way